# Send POST Request to iOS Device

Tags: ios, swift, rest

I have an app that displays a bunch of recipes in a tableview. My goal is that when a user updates a receipe on another device that all devices for that user will be updated. My idea was to have the backend NodeJS server send a POST request to each device to tell them to update the tableview. Is that possible?

Comment: You cannot `POST` to devices. You’ll need to use push notifications if you want your server to tell apps that there is data available.

Comment: @Rob sounds good thanks